# Why do many languages not support nested block comments?

Tags: java, php, html, comments, nested

In most the languages I use, you simply cannot nest block comments, because the first occurrence of the "close" comment syntax closes the comment even if it was only an "inner" comment.

For example, in HTML

```
<!-- outer comment
<p>hello</p><!-- inner comment <p>world</p> -->
<p>this should BE commented</p>
-->
```

in this case, the outer comment ends on the first `-->` instead of the corresponding last one, causing the last `<p>` to print, when it shouldn't.

The same happens for languages that use `/* */` for block comments, like in java, php, css, javascript, etc.

But my question is WHY is it that way? Why, by design, it is not allowed? I mention "by design" because I really doubt it is because of parsing problems, I guess the parsers are perfectly capable of keeping track of opening `/*`s and close the comments with their corresponding closing `*/`s But they simply somehow decided it is not a good idea.

I already know that a workaround for this is to somehow change the inner closing comments, to avoid them to close , and only leave the last closing one. e.g. changing inner `-->`s and `*/`s for `- ->`s and `* /`s . But that is obviously not convenient, and hard to do when you only want to discard blocks of code for debugging purposes. (other techniques are to nest everything in `if(false){}` blocks, but that is not the point here.

So, what I'd like to know is WHY nested comments are generally not allowed in several modern languages? there must be a good reason other than "others don't do it, we won't either" right?.

And as a plus, are there any other (not so obscure) languages that DO allow nested block comments?

Comment: Note that Haskell allows it. I think there are sources claiming it is too much of a pain for the parser, but GHC does it rather nicely.

Comment: HTML is actually a bad example – comments in HTML are more complex.

Comment: youre forgetting taht most of these constraints are >20 years old. it used to be a strain on the parser's resources. anyway, most decent IDSe will allow you to block-comment stuff and take care of the gory details

Comment: @radai Java is not yet 20 years old.

Comment: what will be the advantage of using nested block comments?? To 'be honest I dont see any great benefits

Comment: even if the constraints are old, new versions of the languages should implement it, i guess. (just as they implement any other functionality that would not work on older versions anyway)

Comment: Duplicates: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/81072/why-do-most-programming-languages-not-nest-block-comments and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/116330/why-dont-more-languages-support-recursive-nested-comments

Comment: @ZiyaoWei - java isnt, but it "inherited" c/c++ syntax, which is even older. also, i've seen quite a few places that _RELY_ on this behaviour. "upgrading" parsers could break a lot of code

Comment: @StinePike Nested comment could be used to add a message, while the nesting comment is for disabling some feature.

Comment: There's probably no *good* reason for not nesting comments, but it is a lot easier on the parser because it can ignore everything in the comment block until it reaches an end comment token (`*/`).

Comment: @StinePike because sometimes, for debugging purposes, you would like to discard large blocks of code that may already have block comments, and it is very easy to just wrap them with `/* */` instead of other workarounds.

Comment: Yah ... now that sounds important.. didn't think like that

Comment: For the same reason that strings or variable names can not be nested. They're singular tokens to the tokenizer. Also comments aren't code blocks, thus structuring serves no purpose for the resulting programming logic.

Comment: @mario Actually, some programming languages (e.g. Bash) allow nested strings. And nested variable names also exist (again in Bash, but also, I believe, in PHP).

Comment: @KonradRudolph You're probably referring to variable variables, which is a form of referencing and concatenation, but not an identifer mixup. Can you give an example of bash nested strings? I wasn't referring to escaping and mixed quotes. My hypothetical example being `"aa "bbb "ccc" bb" aa"`, where the resulting string could no longer be a primitive, but a tripple linked list thereof (couldn't make up an accessor syntax for that).

Comment: @mario You’re right about identifiers. But the logic doesn’t carry over to comments. As for strings, Bash is very liberal with interpolation. Such as: `str="Hello $(echo "world")"`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason is historical and has to do with the architecture of compilers.

For the sake of efficiency, most compilers traditionally parse the source code in two stages: the [*lexical analysis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and the actual [*parsing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) of a token stream (that was produced by said lexical analysis). The lexical analysis is the part that recognises individual tokens, such as keywords, strings, number literals – and *comments*.

Again for reasons of efficiency, lexical analysis is traditionally implemented via a [finite-state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_automaton). These finite-state machines happen to recognise (= handle) [regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), which fits perfectly for the above-mentioned tokens. However, it is *not* able to recognise nested constructs – this would require a more powerful machine ([augmented by a stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton)).

Not allowing nested comments was thus simply a decision that traded off convenience for performance, and subsequent languages have by and large adopted the convention.

> And as a plus, are there any other (not so obscure) languages that DO allow nested block comments?

There are some. The comments already mentioned Haskell and Pascal. Other languages are D and F#.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is generally a sloppy, non enforced type of markup.  Browsers had to make decisions between what's right and what's realistic, sometimes they choose the second.

If you really want to comment out a piece of HTML, it's generally not a great idea to even use a single comment with HTML tags inside of it, but it's especially bad to start nesting comments.

You can never be absolutely sure how a browser will handle this when it parses the syntax.

Answer (score -3):

This behavior is exhibited because anything between comment characters is a comment, including more comment characters. Yes, it would be possible to easily program the parser to treat them as nested comments like you describe, but that isn't quite consistent with a comment. A comment is meant to make everything between the open character and close character non-existent, regardless of what it is. Text, code, and comment charcters all get commented out.

Unfortunately, your suggestion that the reason is "other's don't do it, so we won't either" is also quite correct. People expect block comments to behave in a certain way, and get confused when they don't.

Comment: “isn’t quite consistent with a comment” – nonsense. By the same logic a comment would never end because the end-of-comment mark *is part of the comment*. And I’ve yet to see a single person who got confused by nested Haskell or Pascal comments. In fact, the very existence of a concise, formal rule describing nested comments tells as that such a rule *must* be self-consistent. If it weren’t, it couldn’t be formally described.