# why can't we nest one comment inside another comment?

Tags: c, syntax, comments

```
/*
/**hiiii**/
*/
```

Say I nest the comments like this , so what is wrong in this ? At the starting we have `/*` and then some string inside it and then finally we have at the end `*/` , so what is the mistake here ?

Comment: comments stop once they see the matching end of */, if you want a nested comment just use the // inside instead.

Comment: To temporarily disable a section of code that contains comments, use `#if 0`. The alternative provided by some IDE's, is a shortcut key that will convert a section of code to comments by inserting a `//` at the beginning of each line.

Comment: `a = 42; // outer comment // inner, nested comment :)`

Comment: Because the language has been designed that way.

Comment: related: [Why, in general, are nested block comments NOT allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17328276/11107541)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C standard is quite explicit about it. `/*...*/` style comments do not nest, because the language syntax does not allow *nesting*.

Quoting `C11`, chapter 6.4.9, *Comments*, (*emphasis mine*)

> **Except within** a character constant, a string literal, **or a comment, the characters `/*`
>   introduce a comment**. The contents of such a comment are examined only to identify
>   multibyte characters **and to find the characters `*/` that terminate it.**<sup>83)</sup>

and, the related footnote,

> <sub>**83) Thus, `/* ... */` comments do not nest.**</sub>

To elaborate, as in your case,

```
/*                  <-- Comments starts here
/**hiiii**/         <-- Found the ending */, so comment ends.
*/                  <-- problem here....
```

- In the first line, `/*` starts the comment.
- In the second line starting `/*` **does not** start a *new* comment, as mentioned earlier.
- In the second line ending, `*/` terminates the comment. So, in third line, `*/` produces the error.

Comment: This does not answer the question why nested comments may not be used in C.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow "Because" that's the way the language is defined.  This behavior is a good bit older than C11; I seem to recall it working this way in C86, which was pretty new when I learned it.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Well, that depends on the style of comments. `//some //comment` is valid nested comments. isnt it? the `/*..*/` style, OTOH, does not nest.

Answer (score 4):

> > why can't we nest one comment inside another comment?

Because language designers took pity on language implementors.

It is very easy to parse unnestable comments; it is somewhat less easy to parse nestable comments.

```
// pseudo code for unnestable comments
is the character a '*'? YES => Is the next one a '/'? YES END COMMENTS
else STILL INSIDE A COMMENT
```

Comment: pseudo code for nested comments: `inside_comment = 0; if ( "/*" ) inside_comment++; if ( "*/" ) inside_comment--;` So a zero value means you're outside any comment, a positive value means you're inside a comment, and a negative value is an error.

Comment: @user3386109: I didn't say it was difficult :)

Comment: @user3386109 But then the question would be: do `//` nest inside `/* */`?  Would this code declare a variable or not? `/* // */ int x;`.

Comment: Keeping it simple is easier to reason about.  And nesting is usually just for commenting out big chunks of code, which as @chux said, is already available (and better) via `#if 0`.

Answer (score 4):

Code can *effectively* have nested comment behavior with `#if 0`.  So extending `/* */` behavior is not needed.

```
#if 0

   blah blah 

#if 0
   blah blah 

#endif

   blah blah 

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

The */ at the end of the `/**hiiii**/` line is ending the comment.

Do this:

```
/*
//*Hiiii*
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

After seeing `/*` compiler looks for `*/`. Once it find the comment closer `*/`, it's all done. Everything from `/*` to first `*/` regarded as comment. So,

```
/*
/**hiiii**/
```

makes a comment.

The second `*/` is without preceding `/*` and therefore causes an error.

Answer (score 0):

C comments introduced by `/*` do not nest.  This decision was made by the original designers more than 40 years ago and all C Standards make this mandatory. Although some older compilers supported nesting such comments with a command line switch, it is highly recommended to adhere to standard practices and consider that comments end at the first occurrence of the characters `*/`.

Note that `/` and `*` can be separated by an escaped linefeed (a `\` followed by a newline:

```
int i = 3;  /\
* This is a comment (SO syntax coloring is not perfect ;-) *\
/ printf("%d\n", i); // prints 3
```

Also note that it is a bad idea to comment code by turning it into a comment with `/*` `*/`.  If your code contains C comments, this will fail and may even fail silently:

```
int i = 3, j = 6;
/* printf("debug: i=%d\n", i);  /* check the value of i */
printf("debug: j=%d\n", j);  // check the value of j */
```

In the code above, the second `printf` is not *commented*.

You can imagine even more tricky situations:

```
/*
// list all C source files in subdirectories
system("ls */*.[ch]");
*/
```

There are two effective ways to comment a block of code:

- Use `#if 0` / `#endif` preprocessor directives.  These can be nested and easily *uncommented* by changing the `#if 0` into `#if 1`.
- Insert `//` at the beginning of each line in the block.  This can be *nested*, is the sense that you can *comment* a larger block by inserting `//` at the beginning of each line again.