# Why doesn't VS Code highlight my nested multiline JavaScript comment like I expect it to?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, annotations

```
/*/*! why */
annotation*/
```

Does anyone know why annotation is not being annotation in this case?
I checked VS code.

Comment: because the inner  annotation (/*) is part of the comment and the comment will end with the first annotation closing

Answer (score 0):

This is because JavaScript does not have nestable multiline comments (the same goes for plenty of other languages: [Why, in general, are nested block comments NOT allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17328276/11107541)). If you want to read the language spec, see https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-lexical-grammar.html#sec-comments. Your second "`/*`" is treated as part of the multiline comment's body (*MultiLineCommentChars*), and your first "`*/`" closes the multiline comment. Your next line of "`annotation*/`" is outside of any comment, and invalid syntax.